# How to make my footer fit the width of my sidebar with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am designing a template for my website, but as a newbie with Bootstrap 5, I am having a little problem. Specifically, I have a footer that I want to fit the entire width of my sidebar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    <style>
  </style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap  ">
      <div class="col-auto px-0 ">

        <div id="sidebar" class=" collapse collapse-horizontal show border-end  ">


          <div id="sidebar-nav" class=" d-flex list-group border-0 rounded-0 text-sm-start min-vh-100  ">
            <!-- BRANd content goes in here -->
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-sm-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto  text-decoration-none">
              <span class="fs-4 ">Clinique Mangement</span>
            </a>
            <!-- sidebar menu  content goes in here -->
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-house-door"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fs-4 bi-calendar-event"></i> <span >Appointments</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span>Doctors</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span >Users</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span>Patients</span> </a>
            <div class="dropdown bg-dark">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0  text-truncate  dropdown-toggle  bg-dark  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fs-4 bi-bar-chart-line"></i> <span>Reports </span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" data-bs-labelledby="dropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- footer content goes in here -->
            <div class=" d-flex py-sm-0 mt-sm-auto mx-auto  ms-sm-0 flex-shrink-1  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
              <ul class="  list-group list-group-horizontal  ">
                <li class="list-group-item    "> <i class="fa fa-gear fa-lg"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-style-position bg-dark text-white "> <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-lg"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-dark text-white "> <i class="fa fa-eye-slash  fa-lg"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-dark text-white "> <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- main content goes in here -->
      <div class="col d-flex flex-column h-sm-100">
        <main class="row ps-md-0 pt-0">
          <a href="#" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="border rounded-3 p-1 text-decoration-none bg-light"><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-lg py-2 p-1"></i> Menu</a>
          <div class="page-header pt-3">
            <h2>Bootstrap 5 Sidebar Menu - Simple</h2>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of my template:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the following:

- Add the class `w-100` to the parent of the `.list-group`
- Add the class `flex-grow-1` to the `.list-group` and every `.list-group-item`

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid ">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap  ">
      <div class="col-auto px-0 ">

        <div id="sidebar" class=" collapse collapse-horizontal show border-end  ">


          <div id="sidebar-nav" class=" d-flex list-group border-0 rounded-0 text-sm-start min-vh-100  ">
            <!-- BRANd content goes in here -->
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center pb-sm-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto  text-decoration-none">
              <span class="fs-4 ">Clinique Mangement</span>
            </a>
            <!-- sidebar menu  content goes in here -->
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-house-door"></i> <span>Dashboard</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fs-4 bi-calendar-event"></i> <span>Appointments</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span>Doctors</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span>Users</span> </a>
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0 d-inline-block text-truncate " data-bs-parent="#sidebar"> <i class="fs-4 bi-people"></i> <span>Patients</span> </a>
            <div class="dropdown bg-dark">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item border-end-0  text-truncate  dropdown-toggle  bg-dark  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fs-4 bi-bar-chart-line"></i> <span>Reports </span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" data-bs-labelledby="dropdown">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- footer content goes in here -->
            <div class=" d-flex py-sm-0 mt-sm-auto mx-auto w-100  ms-sm-0 flex-shrink-1  " data-bs-parent="#sidebar">
              <ul class="  list-group list-group-horizontal flex-grow-1 ">
                <li class="list-group-item  flex-grow-1  "> <i class="fa fa-gear fa-lg"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-style-position bg-dark text-white "> <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt fa-lg flex-grow-1"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-dark text-white flex-grow-1"> <i class="fa fa-eye-slash  fa-lg"></i></li>
                <li class="list-group-item bg-dark text-white flex-grow-1"> <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-lg"></i></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <!-- main content goes in here -->
      <div class="col d-flex flex-column h-sm-100">
        <main class="row ps-md-0 pt-0">
          <a href="#" data-bs-target="#sidebar" data-bs-toggle="collapse" class="border rounded-3 p-1 text-decoration-none bg-light"><i class="fa fa-list-ul fa-lg py-2 p-1"></i> Menu</a>
          <div class="page-header pt-3">
            <h2>Bootstrap 5 Sidebar Menu - Simple</h2>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```